# Java Import Excel Data into MySQL about encoding

Tags: java, mysql, excel

here my source!!

```
String url    =   "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dahan?characterEncoding=euckr";
String user    =   "root";
String password   =   "pass";

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con = (Connection)                                                      DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);  
        con.setAutoCommit(false);  
        PreparedStatement pstm = null ; 
        PreparedStatement pstm1 = null ; 
        PreparedStatement pstm2 = null ; 
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/hyunwoo/Downloads/Personal Contacts.xls");  
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );  
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);  
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row;
    String del = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dahanMail`";
    String cre = "CREATE TABLE `dahanMail` (`전체이름`  varchar(50),`성`  varchar(50),`이름`  varchar(50) ,`닉네임`  varchar(50),"
            + "`회사`  varchar(500),`부서`  varchar(500),`직급`  varchar(500),`메일주소1`  varchar(50),"
            + "`메일주소2`  varchar(50),`전화번호1`  varchar(50),`전화번호2`  varchar(50),`전화번호3`  varchar(50),"
            + "`휴대폰1`  varchar(50),`휴대폰2`  varchar(50),`팩스1`  varchar(50),`팩스2`  varchar(50),"
            + "`주소`  varchar(50),`웹사이트`  varchar(50),`id`  int NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))";
    pstm1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(del);
    pstm2 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(cre);
    pstm1.execute();
    pstm2.execute();
for(int i=0; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
        row = sheet.getRow(i);
        String fullname = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        String lastname = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        String firstname = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
        String nickname = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
        String company = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
        String sub = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
        String hei = row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue();
        String mailaddress1 = row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue();
        String mailaddress2 = row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue();
        String cnumber1 = row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue();
        String cnumber2 = row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
        String cnumber3 = row.getCell(11).getStringCellValue();
        String pnumber1 = row.getCell(12).getStringCellValue();
        String pnumber2 = row.getCell(13).getStringCellValue();
        String fax1 = row.getCell(14).getStringCellValue();
        String fax2 = row.getCell(15).getStringCellValue();
        String address = row.getCell(16).getStringCellValue();
        String website = row.getCell(17).getStringCellValue();
        int id = (int) row.getCell(18).getNumericCellValue();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO dahanmail VALUES('"+fullname+"','"+lastname+"','"+firstname+"'"
                        + ",'"+nickname+"','"+company+"','"+sub+"','"+hei+"','"+mailaddress1+"','"+mailaddress2+"','"+cnumber1+"','"+cnumber2+"','"+cnumber3+"'"
                                        + ",'"+pnumber1+"','"+pnumber2+"','"+fax1+"','"+fax2+"',"
                                                + "'"+address+"','"+website+"','"+id+"')";

       pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

       pstm.execute();
       System.out.println("Import rows "+i);
       }
       con.commit();
       pstm.close();
       con.close();
       input.close();
       System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
```

I have saved the excel data to mysql using the POI in Java
and It works well!
so I checked the mysql table in cmd 
but console window still show broken language like "???"
it seems to be encoding problem...
How can I change the source to fix the encoding problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have looks like it's close to working, but there are some things I would change:

Firstly, declare your SQL before the loop, with ?'s for value placeholders:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO dahanmail VALUES(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

(I have not put enough `?`s in the code above, there should be one for each value)

Then, in the loop, you can set the parameters:

```
pstm.setString(1,row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
pstm.setString(2,row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
//one for each value. You could use another loop.
```

Then (still in the loop), execute the statement:

```
pstm.execute();
```

Finally clear the parameters for next time round:

```
pstm.clearParameters();
```

Comment: I skipped the source to my mistakes and change the source and this source work well, and I want to show korean language in console windows not broken text. thanks your answer

Comment: I think using the parameters placeholders, as described above, might solve your encoding problems.

Comment: could you give me a example source?

Comment: it occured same encoding problem...how to write encoding code in my source such as utf-8, euc-kr?